# Check for part of a folder name in applescript

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript that checks for one of several external HDs I connect to my computer and makes an index of their contents. All the HDs follow the naming scheme HK_12345 where the first two letters are always the same but the numbers are different for each drive. I want the script to only check for drives with the 'HK' designation regardless of the ending numbers. I have this but it is not working. Any advice?

```
set folderContains to "HK_"

tell application "Finder"
    set triggerFolder to folder whose name contains folderContains
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    if folder triggerFolder exists then
    -- some other code
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `disks` not `folders`:

```
set diskContains to "HK_"

tell application "Finder"
    set selectedDisks to disks whose name contains diskContains
    -- some other code
end tell
```